# Как сформировать SOAP запрос(есть отдельно xsd и wdsl)

Tags: java, soap, xsd, wsdl

Есть xsd файл для формирования запроса (возможно я не правильно выражаюсь, из данной схемы я формирую xml файл, если что поправьте меня) и сам wsdl файл который как бы описывает доступ к этому сервису который ждет от меня данный xml файл. Как мне связать эти два файла и в итоге отправить запрос на сервис?

Сам wsdl я беру отсюда: http://ruzditest.eisnot.ru:8280/services/ruzdiUploadNotificationPackageService_v1_0?wsdl

xsd файл https://yadi.sk/d/Zr5n4cje34P5BA

PS
xml файл я сделал из xsd файла а вот дальше застрял

Comment: Вы пишете приложение для этого сервиса на Java? Или вам просто нужно единоразово что-то отправить?

Comment: @V.Makhnutin первый вариант. Мне необходимо регулярно туда это отправлять.

Comment: один из самых простых и быстрых способов это spring ws + spring boot http://spring-projects.ru/guides/consuming-web-service/

Comment: @V.Makhnutin у меня пока основная проблема что я пока не понимаю как связать эти два файла....

Comment: не совсем понимаю, вы хотите руками делать xml файлы для сервиса, и отдавать их потом программе чтобы она отправляла его?

Comment: @V.Makhnutin нет, я с начало на java с помощью jaxb формирую "xml"-объект а затем по идее должен передать его в SOAP. Но там загвоздка что я не могу не с помощью xjc не с помощью wsimport получить java - класс для отправки это xml объекта